# Problem with Fluids Tespassing Obstacles (bottles, cauldrons)

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I have problems with physics.

I modeled a bottle and I duplicated part of the bottle for the liquid. The liquid has a face on top so it is closed. The bottle is open on top.

[image]

[image]

I added a cube for the Domain which covers the entire object and the bottle's animation.

Set the bottle as Fluid/Obstacle and selected Shell as Volume Initialization (with Volume it does not work) and had a modifier of thickness 0.1.

Set the fluid as fluid and Volume as Volume Initialization.

And when I bake this is what happens: the Domain, already as a fluid, trespasses the bottle and, later, it does not drop from the bottle.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:** I made a new bottle to try thickness and increase resolution to 150 (also tried 300 but the result was the same quality as for 150). And now, with this new bottle I can't get a glass material for it.

Here you are the Blender file [image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is probably because the fluid is low quality. Try increasing the fluid quality, and subdivisions + smoothing.

Comment: Don't compound new questions into the original post. Keep different questions separate. Use the  blue [**Ask Question**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) box at the top right of the page.

Comment: The additional question posted as a edit to this question has spun off to: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/162934/16395.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your resolution is too low. Try setting it to at least 150** but preferably more.

Yes, this will mean longer simulation times, but that's the catch with all simulations!

The resolution determines the size of the grid elements used by the simulation engine: your elements are so big (you can see the big blocks in your screenshots) that the walls are too thin for the fluid to notice, and that the hole is too narrow for the fluid to pass through!

---

**Edit** (after seeing your file): **how to fix the obstacle**

I forgot about this! Your obstacle should be solid in the Mesh data: this means that your flask must have the solidify modifier applied, not in the stack! I suggest doing this:

- Set up (as you've done) the bottle, with the animation data and everything.
- Duplicate the bottle. The original bottle will be use for rendering, the copy ONLY for simulation.
- On the original bottle, remove Fluid physics, and remove the solidify modifier
- On the new copied bottle, use a *negative* value for the solidify thickness (worked for me with -0.14) and **apply the solidify modifier**.
- You can restrict the bottle visibility, and also you should remove it from the render layers

  [image]
- Run the simulation.
- Restrict also the normal visibility ("eye" icon) of the duplicated bottle
- Take care of the appearance of the "rendered" original bottle. For example a solidify with thickness = -0.07 works well.

  [image]

---

<sup>PS: As regards your glass material: I've created a question & answer here: [My glass material isn't transparent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/162934/16395)</sup>

Comment: Oh, man, you are my hero. It has a better result now but I still have the same problem. I increased the quality from 65 to 149 and it stills trespasses the bottle but much less thanb before.What can I do? Still increase the quality?

Comment: yes, increase resolution and if you can't afford the longer simulation time, thicken your solidified walls a bit (then, after baking, you can revert to the original thickness)

Comment: Hi, it always trespasses, I don't know why. I changed thickness to 0.16m and increased resolution to 300 and still trespasses the bottle. What else can I do?

Comment: I wouldn't know at this point honestly. Would you like to [upload the latest version of your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for me to check?

Comment: I edited original post with new information and Blender file. This is a new bottle to try thickness because the original one was too small, I think. I have the same problems in this new bottle with a resolution of 300, 200 and 150, after increasing thickness and, now, I can't get a glass material with this new bottle. I can't see the fluid inside. Thank you for your time, Nicola.

Comment: For newer questions please ask on a different post.

Comment: @Dunadan I forgot to mention an important point in my answer, and that's why my earlier solution didn't help you solve the problem. I have updated my answer. I hope it now works fine.

Comment: Now it works perfectly. I can try more options thanks to your help, Nicola.

I'm sorry Cegaton. It won't happen in the future.