# My glass material isn't transparent in Eevee

Tags: rendering, shaders, transparency, eevee-render-engine, glass

When using Eevee, an object with a glass material (in this case: *Principled BSDF*, trasmission set to 1.0) doesn't seem like it can be looked through: it's completely opaque.

See for instance the material for the blue cube in this scene:

[image]

How can I get my glass material to be transparent?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, some options that require extra computing efforts are turned off in Eevee and they must be turned on manually.

In the case of a refractive object, you must enable:

- Under the *Render* settings, ***Screen Space Reflections*** and, within it, ***Refraction***. <sup>[manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/screen_space_reflections.html).</sup>

  [image]
- Then, in each of your refractive materials' *Material settings*, you should enable ***Screen Space Refraction***. <sup>[manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#screen-space-refraction).</sup>

  [image]

If your material has some kind of Alpha transparency (e.g. a Transparent BSDF shader), you should also select a suitable *Blend Mode*. <sup>[manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#blend-mode).</sup>

Comment: Great Q&A. Can't even remember how many people I referred to it :).

Comment: Fun fact: these options have already changed spots in Blender 3.1.2. Screen Space Refraction, for example, is under Viewport Display > Settings. "Screen Space Reflections" however is nowhere to be found in the Sampling tab or when I search for it. Back to Blender 2.7 I go once more... what a nightmare