# Odd finish appearing on object

Tags: modeling

Perhaps it was too complicated for some the first time asking about this issue. I created a cup following a tutorial and it has a glass finish. It renders as a glass finish, however when viewing it material preview mode it has an odd finish. Does anyone know why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Material preview mode uses a hidden HDRI to provide fast reflections and lighting for your object.

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Is the question to complicated for this forum? Why do you keep deleting it before answered?

Comment: Hello :). You need to make your glass transparent in Eevee: [My glass material isn't transparent in Eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/162934/78972)